# why date utils return different output?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs, date-formatting, date-fns

I am trying to convert UTC to local timezone date format or where user run that program .my program is working fine using `moment js`.

**working fine as expected result**
here is my code
/.
https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-darwin-s60d66?file=/src/App.js

```
const time = "2023-03-07 06:27:06"; // UTC time

export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(
      "output",
      moment.parseZone(moment(time)).local().format("DD-MMM-YYYY hh:mm a")
    );
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
```

**NOT working correctly . Not returning correct output why** ?. I am trying to do same thing using **date-fns** library but giving wrong output

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-zhukovsky-20eh2n?file=/src/App.js:150-198

```
const time = "2023-03-07 06:27:06"; // UTC time
const parsedTime = parseISO(time);

const formatInTimeZone = (date, fmt, tz) =>
  format(utcToZonedTime(date, tz), fmt, { timeZone: tz });

// Get the machine's local timezone

export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const localTimeZone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;

    const formattedTime = formatInTimeZone(
      parsedTime,
      "dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm a",
      localTimeZone // Use the local timezone here
    );
    console.log(formattedTime);
  }, []);
```

I am in ASIA local timezone
[image]

any sugestion ?

Answer (score 0):

parseISO will take into consideration if the time is UTC or not. In order to specify if it is UTC you must put Z at the end of your string. Your code will look like this:

```
const time = "2023-03-07 06:27:06Z"; // UTC time
const parsedTime = parseISO(time);
```